# VPN connects but remote network not accessible

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, vpn

I'm having a sudden issue. My workplace set up a VPN last month in preparation for working at home, and it worked fine. I stopped using it about two weeks ago. Now I need to use it again and it stopped functioning.

According to my coworker the server hasn't changed in a month, not even updates. I update/upgrade my client regularly (kernel is at 5.3.0-46-generic now).

I'm using the built-in VPN client of Ubuntu (in the network GUI) with authentication methods MSCHAP and MSCHAPv2

The symptoms are:

- `ping` to internet IPs work
- `ping` and `host` to internet addresses work (DNS resolves work)
- `ping` to VPN server works
- `ping` to other computer at work doesn't work anymore (one such computer is accessible through it's web interface so it's running and the IP (static route) hasn't changed)
- `traceroute` to internet IP doesn't show any route through work (this was through work before)

Some extra information:

`cat /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search dynamic.ziggo.nl
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Difference in `ifconfig` after enabling VPN:

```
ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1400
        inet 192.168.178.231  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 192.168.178.81
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 7  bytes 94 (94.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7  bytes 112 (112.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Excerpt from `cat /var/log/syslog|grep NetworkManager`:

```
Apr  8 08:33:42 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327622.2340] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860" name="VPN connection 1" pid=2325 uid=1000 result="success"
Apr  8 08:33:42 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327622.2375] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc2e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 3857
Apr  8 08:33:42 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327622.2428] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc2e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Apr  8 08:33:42 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327622.3015] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc2e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Apr  8 08:33:42 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327622.3270] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc2e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Apr  8 08:33:42 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Apr  8 08:33:42 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: Using interface ppp0
Apr  8 08:33:42 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
Apr  8 08:33:42 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327622.3338] manager: (ppp0): new Ppp device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Apr  8 08:33:42 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327622.3411] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Apr  8 08:33:42 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327622.3411] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: local  IP address 192.168.178.231
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: remote IP address 192.168.178.81
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: primary   DNS address 1.1.1.1
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: secondary DNS address 1.1.1.1
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327623.4665] device (ppp0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327623.4673] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc2e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",0]: VPN connection: (IP4 Config Get) reply received from old-style plugin
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327623.4678] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc2e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",4:(ppp0)]: Data: VPN Gateway: 213.233.219.244
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327623.4678] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc2e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",4:(ppp0)]: Data: Tunnel Device: "ppp0"
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327623.4678] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc2e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",4:(ppp0)]: Data: IPv4 configuration:
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327623.4678] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc2e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",4:(ppp0)]: Data:   Internal Address: 192.168.178.231
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327623.4678] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc2e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",4:(ppp0)]: Data:   Internal Prefix: 32
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327623.4679] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc2e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",4:(ppp0)]: Data:   Internal Point-to-Point Address: 192.168.178.81
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327623.4679] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc2e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",4:(ppp0)]: Data:   Static Route: 192.168.178.81/32   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327623.4679] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc2e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",4:(ppp0)]: Data:   Internal DNS: 1.1.1.1
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327623.4679] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc2e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",4:(ppp0)]: Data:   DNS Domain: '(none)'
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327623.4679] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc2e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",4:(ppp0)]: Data: No IPv6 configuration
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327623.4680] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc2e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",4:(ppp0)]: VPN plugin: state changed: started (4)
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327623.4680] device (ppp0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586327623.4695] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc2e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",4:(ppp0)]: VPN connection: (IP Config Get) complete
Apr  8 08:33:43 pc-2019 dbus-daemon[1004]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=0 pid=1027 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
```

I don't have the syslog from last month anymore because it's more than 7 days ago, so I can't compare at which step it starts to differ.

`syslog` When disabling my vpn (note the `Sent 0 bytes`):

```
Apr  8 09:44:23 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586331863.7062] audit: op="connection-deactivate" uuid="ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860" name="VPN connection 1" pid=2325 uid=1000 result="success"
Apr  8 09:44:23 pc-2019 dbus-daemon[1004]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=0 pid=1027 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Apr  8 09:44:23 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: Terminating on signal 15
Apr  8 09:44:23 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: Connect time 8.3 minutes.
Apr  8 09:44:23 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: Sent 0 bytes, received 4546 bytes.
Apr  8 09:44:23 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: MPPE disabled
Apr  8 09:44:23 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: Child process /usr/sbin/pptp 213.233.219.244 --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring nm-pptp-service-8228 (pid 8239) terminated with signal 15
Apr  8 09:44:23 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586331863.7090] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc6e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Apr  8 09:44:23 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586331863.7090] vpn-connection[0x55de7e6cc6e0,ffc0be21-f339-4781-9868-c36d8bd08860,"VPN connection 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Apr  8 09:44:23 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586331863.7099] device (ppp0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Apr  8 09:44:23 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: Connection terminated.
Apr  8 09:44:23 pc-2019 NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1586331863.7298] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
```

Any idea how this might be resolved?

[As requested]:

```
mark@pc-2019:~$ ip r
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp34s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp34s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp34s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.23 metric 100 
213.233.219.244 via 192.168.1.1 dev enp34s0 src 192.168.1.23 
mark@pc-2019:~$ ip r
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp34s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp34s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp34s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.23 metric 100 
192.168.1.1 dev enp34s0 proto static scope link metric 100 
192.168.178.81 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.245 metric 50 
213.233.219.244 via 192.168.1.1 dev enp34s0 src 192.168.1.23 
213.233.219.244 via 192.168.1.1 dev enp34s0 proto static metric 100
```

Note: enp34s0 = local adapter (something like eth0)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `ip r` while connected to VPN, and while not connected.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added the output.